# AWS CDK: run external build command in CDK sequence?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Is it possible to run an external build command as part of a CDK stack sequence? Intention: 1) create a rest API, 2) write rest URL to config file, 3) build and deploy a React app:

```ts
import apigateway = require('@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway');
import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
import fs = require('fs')
import s3deployment = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment');

export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {

  const restApi = new apigateway.RestApi(this, ..);
  fs.writeFile('src/app-config.json', 
    JSON.stringify({ "api": restApi.deploymentStage.urlForPath('/myResource') }))

  // TODO locally run 'npm run build', create 'build' folder incl rest api config

  const websiteBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, ..)
  new s3deployment.BucketDeployment(this, .. {
      sources: [s3deployment.Source.asset('build')],
      destinationBucket: websiteBucket
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Related: create-react-app urls configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51401640/3633993

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, as the necessary references are only available after deploy and therefore after you try to write the file (the file will contain [cdk tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/tokens.html)).

I personally have solved this problem by telling cdk to output the apigateway URLs to a file and then parse it *after* the deploy to upload it so a S3 bucket, to do it you need:

- deploy with the output file options, for example:
  `cdk deploy -O ./cdk.out/deploy-output.json`
- In `./cdk.out/deploy-output.json` you will find a JSON object with a key for each stack that produced an output (e.g. your stack that contains an API gateway)
- manually parse that JSON to get your apigateway url
- create your configuration file and upload it to S3 (you can do it via aws-sdk)

Of course, you have the last steps in a custom script, which means that you have to wrap your `cdk deploy`. I suggest to do so with a nodejs script, so that you can leverage aws-sdk to upload your file to S3 easily.

Comment: This approach makes sense. Reading it I wondered: do we need to "manually" parse the json or is there a better way?

Comment: Well, it's pretty easy to read and parse a JSON file in javascript/typescript, there are plenty of ways that don't require more than a couple of lines of code, for example:

```
const outputFile = JSON.parse(
        readFileSync(__dirname + '/../dir/cdk.out/build-output.json', { encoding: 'UTF-8' }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Accepting that cdk doesn't support this, I split logic into two cdk scripts, accessed API gateway URL as cdk output via the cli, then wrapped everything in a bash script.

AWS CDK:

```ts
// API gateway
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'my-api', ..)

// output url
const myResourceURL = api.deploymentStage.urlForPath('/myResource');
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'MyRestURL', { value: myResourceURL });
```

Bash:

```bash
# deploy api gw
cdk deploy --app (..)  

# read url via cli with --query
export rest_url=`aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name (..) --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='MyRestURL'].OutputValue" --output text`

# configure React app
echo "{ \"api\" : { \"invokeUrl\" : \"$rest_url\" } }" > src/app-config.json

# build React app with url
npm run build

# run second cdk app to deploy React built output folder
cdk deploy --app (..)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe use GitHub Actions or some other CI tool to manage these steps

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue:

- Needed to build and upload react-app as well
- Supported dynamic configuration reading from react-app - look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401640/reading-environment-variable-in-run-time-after-running-npm-build-for-a-create-re/63836887#63836887)
- Released my react-app with specific version (in a separate flow)
- Then, during CDK deployment of my app, it took a specific version of my react-app (version retrieved from local configuration) and uploaded its zip file to S3 bucket using CDK BucketDeployment
- Then, using AwsCustomResource I generated a configuration file with references to Cognito and API-GW and uploaded this file to S3 as well:

```js
        // create s3 bucket for react-app
        const uiBucket = new Bucket(this, "ui", {
            bucketName: this.stackName + "-s3-react-app",
            blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL
        });

       
        let confObj = {
            "myjsonobj" : {
                "region": `${this.region}`,
                "identity_pool_id": `${props.CognitoIdentityPool.ref}`,
                "myBackend": `${apiGw.deploymentStage.urlForPath("/")}`
            }
        };


        const dataString = JSON.stringify(confObj, null, 4);

        
        const bucketDeployment = new BucketDeployment(this, this.stackName + "-app", {
            destinationBucket: uiBucket,
            sources: [Source.asset(`reactapp-v1.zip`)]
        });

        bucketDeployment.node.addDependency(uiBucket)

        const s3Upload = new custom.AwsCustomResource(this, 'config-json', {
            policy: custom.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({resources: custom.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE}),
            onCreate: {
                service: "S3",
                action: "putObject",
                parameters: {
                    Body: dataString,
                    Bucket: `${uiBucket.bucketName}`,
                    Key: "app-config.json",
                },
                physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of(`${uiBucket.bucketName}`)
            }
        });
        s3Upload.node.addDependency(bucketDeployment);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this isn't supported within CDK. So this how we solved it in SST: https://github.com/serverless-stack/serverless-stack

1. On the CDK side, allow defining React environment variables using the outputs of other constructs.

   ```js
   // Create a React.js app
   const site = new sst.ReactStaticSite(this, "Site", {
     path: "frontend",
     environment: {
       // Pass in the API endpoint to our app
       REACT_APP_API_URL: api.url,
     },
   });
   ```
2. Spit out a config file while starting the local environment for the backend.
3. Then start React using `sst-env -- react-scripts start`, where we have [a simple CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@serverless-stack/static-site-env) that reads from the config file and loads them as build-time environment variables in React.
4. While deploying, replace these environment variables inside a custom resource based on the outputs.

We wrote about it here: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/setting-serverless-environments-variables-in-a-react-app.html

And here's the source for the [`ReactStaticSite`](https://github.com/serverless-stack/serverless-stack/blob/master/packages/resources/src/ReactStaticSite.ts) and [`StaticSite`](https://github.com/serverless-stack/serverless-stack/blob/master/packages/resources/src/StaticSite.ts) constructs for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using the Python language for CDK.  I have a Makefile which I invoke directly from my app.py like this:
`os.system("make")`.  I use the make to build up a layer zip file per [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). Technically you can invoke whatever you'd like.   You must import the os package of course.  Hope this helps.