# Rename a S3 file using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, clouddevelopmentkit

I wish to rename a file that exists in S3 using CDK. That's pretty much it. The closest thing I found was [BucketDeployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3-deployment.BucketDeployment.html) and it doesn't work for this purpose. Is there a way to do this, or should I just write a lambda?

Comment: If it is just a file, why not manually rename it? To my understanding CDK is for provisioning resources (IaC). Is renaming a necessary step in your deployment?

Comment: Manual steps, are, a manual touchpoint. Yes, CDK is IAC and I'd like to automate e2e. Further context - I just want to add an extension at the end so that the consumer can understand the file being passed

Comment: I see. Instead of Lambda, I think it is easier to just create a custom script? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715131/aws-cdk-run-external-build-command-in-cdk-sequence

Comment: You can use a step function SDK call to do this.

Comment: @AviJain I agree with Allan Chua's answer, but if you still want to go ahead with a pure CDK based approach, you can create a Lambda backed custom resource using the [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/custom-resources-readme.html) module. You might already know this since you mentioned Lambda in your question.

Comment: For anybody else looking at this, yep, the custom resource thing works, and one can make a SDK call with it (S3 in this case, don't need to "write" a lambda)

Answer (score 0):

AWS CDK's main purpose is to provision infrastructure. Managing the data stored on those infrastructure is an entirely different story.

**Deploying Updates to Static Site**
If the goal of this rename operation is for deployment purposes, I would suggest to just use AWS CLI, this makes release process much simpler with less risk as the underlying infrastructure is not at risk of unintentional modifications / bugs in the updates made on the infrastructure's CDK templates.

This option makes mounting on a CI/CD pipeline much more simpler too!

**Managing application data**
If the goal of this rename is to manage application data, I would suggest using AWS SDK for your language of choice.

Layering automation is a subtle best practice! Using these automation tools for the right goal / use-cases can empower us to deliver changes quicker to customers!